# Bad font color choice for close stats review tool

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, 10k-tools

I just discovered [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=today) which appears to have a very light gray font on a white background.

How page looks :
[image]

How it looks when text on page is highlighted :
[image]

Not sure if this is the only screen which uses that font color choice, but I figured I'd point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light grey color is there on purpose - to indicate these are off-topic close reasons that are **not** active.

---

I've reviewed the color choice and changed the styling to .5 opacity instead. With you in the next build.

Comment: So don't show them at all - they're 99.9999% invisible unless I tilt my head to a very specific angle.

Comment: The muted color was by the community request - I'll see if I can make it stand out a bit more.

Comment: Why not same design as highly downvoted answers, or even ignored tags? re-inventing the wheel always has the risk of producing a square wheel by mistake...

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks for the explanation. I don't think I agree with the decision to use a color so light that it's almost invisible on most monitors though, and agree with @ShadowWizard that it should either be hidden, moved/collapsed, or styled a bit darker :)

Comment: @Rachel knowing Oded, he might still change it. Let's cross our fingers! :)

Comment: Waiting to see the result...